# MVC 4.0 Show simple grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to mvc, and i'm now trying to show a simple gridview which will be loaded from my sql server.
I can't even find the gridview in the toolbox.

i'm using the razor view engine.
example will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use Webforms, why don't you just use Webforms?

Comment: Because the company i work for decided to work with mvc. I do think winforms is better. faster development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention mvc and toolbox.  Those are incompatible concepts.  You don't drag things out of the toolbox in MVC like you do in Web Forms.  You type out various fields using html helpers.

While there is, in fact, a WebGrid available (quite a few actually), you would be better suited (at least initially) doing a manual table generation.  Once you understand how it works, then you can move on to more advanced uses.

Any good MVC tutorial should have an example, such as MVC Music Store, or Nerd Dinner.